# Matrice application on finite sets

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A=(a_{i,j})$ a Matrix in $M_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$  such that $ a_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$ for all $1\leq i,j \leq n$ , And
 there is $m,r \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ such that : $ ~^tAA=mI_{n}+r J$ , where $J$ is the matrix with all coefficients equal to $1$ .
Prove that $~^tAA=A~^tA$ . 
Application : Let $E$ a finite set , $n \geq 1$ a positive integer , $E_{1},...,E_{n}$ subsets of $E$  , such that that  for $1\leq i \leq n$:  $|E_{i}|=m+r$ and for $i<j$ , $|E_{i} \cap E_{j}|=r$ , what can we deduce from the above result ?

I didn't succeed to solve the question  :(  , all I have done so far is : we can notice that $A$ is inversible and ,  from : 
$A^{t}AA=mA+rAJ$ , and $~^{t}AAA=mA+rJA$  combining the two we get : $(^{t}AA-A^{t}A)A=r(JA-AJ)$  since $A$ is inversible it suffice to prove that 
$JA=AJ$ . Any help ? Thank you .

Comment: What does $^t A$ mean? Is it the transpose of $A$?

Comment: @pepa.dvorak yes

Answer (score 0):

it took me a long while to notice that since $a_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}$ the coefficients of the matrix are solution of  the equation $x^{2}=x$  , now I can finish the solution , considering  the diagonal coefficient of $~^{t}AA$  we have  for all $i$ ; $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k,i}^{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k,i}=m+r$ hence the sum on  the columns is constants , as we wanted , for the sum on the lines ,  just combine the two equality ; 
$ ~^{t}AAV=(m+rn)V$ and $~^{t}AV=(m+r)V$  where $V=~^{t}(1,....,1)$  , hence since $A$ is inversible $~^{t}A$ too hence the application $X \to ~^{t}AX$ is bijective , this force $AV=\frac{m+rn}{m+r}V$  hence for all $i$  , $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{i,k}=\frac{m+rn}{m+r}$  , it suffice to show that 
$(m+rn)^{2}=m+r$  which is obivious Done!   :)